# Pass data of the same component between different Screens in Angular 13

Tags: angular, service, angular-ui-router

I have one input query component, which handles data request. This input component will be used in two different components locations (in screen A and in screen B).

When the input query is finished, the navigation will always go to screen B component to present the query data and also the requested data. The following image shows the structure of the data flow.

Data flow:

[image: Data flow diagram between "Screen A" with an input component and "Screen B" with an input component and some data]

What is the best practice to pass data around here? I used multiple input & output in the input query component, to pass data around, but it was overloaded. Does a data service makes sense?

Comment: In simple applications you should think about a service, which is injected into both components. In larger application best practice is to have a store.

Comment: You do not have any code example in the question, so it's difficult to predict how both your components are interacting. You said screen is navigating to different route, meaning it's not parent-child relation, so @Input() won't work of course.

You would need to use Subject/BehaviorSubject, where comp A publishes the data to the subject, and comp B subscribes to the observable, and fetches latest data each time.